# When I create a Temporary File/Directory, when will it be removed?

Tags: linux, julia, temporary-files

Julia contains a [number of methods](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/file/#Base.mktemp) for making temporary files and directories.

I'm making fairly heavy use of them (and `/dev/shm`), to inferface with libraries that really want to work with actual files (JLD/HDF5, and OpenStack Swift).

I had been assuming they would be deleted when their finalisers on the pointer to there name were called.
But then after exiting julia it seemed like they were all still there.

Will linux delete them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the app didn't clean after itself, the OS will delete the files eventually. It depends on system settings when temp files are deleted. For example, it can happen on boot or nightly (via cron job) or some another way.

See this answer, for example: [How is the /tmp directory cleaned up?](https://askubuntu.com/a/759048)

Answer (score 3):

What you are likely looking for,
given your surprise that they were not removed, based on going out of scope, as the do block versions of `mktemp`.
In the very [documentation you linked](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/file/#Base.mktemp).

> **mktemp**(f::Function[, parent=tempdir()])
>
> Apply the function f to the result of mktemp(parent) and remove the temporary file upon completion.
>
> **mktempdir**(f::Function[, parent=tempdir()])
>
> Apply the function f to the result of mktempdir(parent) and remove the temporary directory upon completion.

Which you can use like:

```
mktempdir("/dev/shm") do tdir
    fname = joinpath(tdir, name)
    #Do some things with your new temp filename `fname` in your tempdir `tdir`
end
#the directory referenced by `tdir`, and `fname`, have now been deleted.
```